# How to create a list of lists with tags in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn how to create a list of lists with the outer and inner list containing list tags.  For example:

```
list1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
list2 <- list(d = 4, e = 5, g = 6)
list3 <- list(h = 7, i = 8, j = 9)

cc_list <- list()
cc_list$foo <- list1
cc_list$bar <- list2
cc_list
```

The output from above is as follows:

```
$foo
$foo$a
[1] 1

$foo$b
[1] 2

$foo$c
[1] 3


$bar
$bar$d
[1] 4

$bar$e
[1] 5

$bar$g
[1] 6
```

Note that the format is exactly what I am looking for.  The list is extremely easy to access.  For example, I can access list1 element 'a' in the concatenated list with cc_list$foo$a.

```
cc_list$foo$a
[1] 1
```

But, now I want to build the same kind of list using variables and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.  For example, the following is an example of what I want to do but it doesn't work.  Essentially, I'm trying to create a duplicate of the nicely formatted list above but this time I want to use variables var_tag1 instead of the literal string "foo" and var_tag2 instead of the literal string "bar":

```
var_tag1 <- "foo"
var_tag2 <- "bar"
cc_list$var_tag1 <- list1
cc_list$var_tag2 <- list2
```

How do I use variables to create the nice tag naming structure so that I can access the list using tags?

Comment: Use `cc_list[[var_tag1]] <- list1`, etc.

Comment: And if you want to search for duplicate questions may I suggest the phrase "key-value pairs"?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Richard Scriven in the comments above:

Use cc_list[[var_tag1]] <- list1, etc